# Right way to multiply integrals.. as a normal product or as a wedge product?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral, exterior-algebra

This is a well-known identity:

$$
\left( \int_{\Delta x}g(x)dx \right)\left( \int_{\Delta y} f(y) dy \right)=\int_{\Delta x}\int_{\Delta y}g(x)f(y)dxdy \tag{1}
$$

But I am wondering if we may be missing out on something important by doing so.

Consider two parametrized line elements :

$$
(ds_\lambda)^2 = \eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial g(\lambda)^\mu}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial g(\lambda)^\nu}{\partial \lambda}  \\
(ds_\beta)^2 = \eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial f(\beta)^\mu}{\partial \beta} \frac{\partial f(\beta)^\nu}{\partial \beta}  \\
$$

Now applying Identity (1) to the line elements, I get

$$
\left( \int_{\Delta \lambda} \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial g(\lambda)^\mu}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial g(\lambda)^\nu}{\partial \lambda}} d\lambda \right)\left( \int_{\Delta \beta} \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial f(\beta)^\mu}{\partial \beta} \frac{\partial f(\beta)^\nu}{\partial \beta}} d\beta \right) \\
=  \int_{\Delta \lambda}  \int_{\Delta \beta} \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial g(\lambda)^\mu}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial g(\lambda)^\nu}{\partial \lambda} \eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{\partial f(\beta)^\mu}{\partial \beta} \frac{\partial f(\beta)^\nu}{\partial \beta}} d\lambda d\beta 
$$

This seems close to the definition of the area integral involving the determinant, but not quite.

---

However, if I multiply the integrals using the wedge product:

$$
\left( \int_{\Delta x}g(x)dx \right) \wedge \left( \int_{\Delta y} f(y) dy \right)
$$

Can I recover the correct area integration formula:

$$
\iint \sqrt{\det g_{\mu\nu}}dxdy
$$

I expect that it is possible?